# Dual boot Ubuntu on Mid 2010 MacBook Pro questions

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, macbook, refind

I don't know if this is the *best* place to ask this, if not please point me in that direction and I will remove this clutter. Anyways, I installed Ubuntu on my Macbook Pro and it runs fantastic. Though it doesn't seem to run REFInd correctly. When I power the device on it just boots straight into Ubuntu without REFInd showing up at all. If I hold alt/option I can select Macintosh HD and boot into that but no sign of REFInd.

Here is the output of efibootmgr

```
$ efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 5 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0080
Boot0000*: ubuntu
Boot0080* Mac OS X
Boot0082*
BootFFFF*
```

Dunno if I just need to change the boot order or what, but any help is much appreciated!

EDIT: Adding sudo efibootmgr -v per Rod Smith's request

```
$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 5 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0080
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,8a37fe56-dbb9-4da1-87b1-75c64e3502d9,0x28,0x64000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0080* Mac OS X  HD(1,GPT,8a37fe56-dbb9-4da1-87b1-75c64e3502d9,0x28,0x64000)/File(\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi)
Boot0082*   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x2)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(3,GPT,53f4b670-a0df-4947-b5d2-24e5b25beb79,0x745d0e68,0x135f20)
BootFFFF*   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x2)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(3,GPT,53f4b670-a0df-4947-b5d2-24e5b25beb79,0x68cb8b88,0x135f20)/File(\System\Library\CoreServices\boot.efi)
```

Comment: Please show the output of `sudo efibootmgr -v`. That provides additional information that's necessary to provide a proper answer. Possibly re-ordering the existing boot entries will work; or you might need to add a new one. [This page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html) (part of the rEFInd documentation) may be generally helpful, but does not provide a simple and direct answer to your specific question.

Comment: @RodSmith I added the command as an edit above so it could be better formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu, run (via `sudo`) the `refind-mkdefault` script that comes with rEFInd. Alternatively, you could type:

```
sudo efibootmgr -o 0080,0000
```

Either action should fix your problem.

Be aware, however, that either Ubuntu or OS X might change the default in the future. That's the point of [this page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html) of the rEFInd documentation, which describes the causes and ways to recover from such problems.

Comment: That did the trick. I had to use the efibootmgr command cause it said refind-mkdefault wasn't found. But either way it works now! Thanks!

Comment: If you installed rEFInd from OS X, the script would be in the `.zip` file you downloaded, not installed in Ubuntu, so you'd need to run it from there. For a one-time use, running `efibootmgr` to re-order the boot options would be easier. If you want to set up something to automatically check and adjust the boot order, you'd need to copy over the script to `/usr/local/bin` (or some other convenient location) in Ubuntu.